# Angular 7 subscribe method (observable issue) doesn't work when you run ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 on mobile browsers

Tags: web, mobile, observable, subscribe

I have a problem with my Angular app. I am testing an application with ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 using my android and ios phones and when I use an observable, the observable is not executing. What is strange is that on my desktop, it works perfectly fine and I don't have any error in my console. I just figured out that there is an issue with the observable because I did some alert() functions and on desktop I was able to see them, but on my phone I wasn't. Do I have to install any modules in order to 
make the observable compatible with mobile browsers ? Also when I simulate them on my desktop chrome's console and select a specific phone, let's say Iphone 5, the code works fine, the problem is when I am testing with the real devices.
  Note that the angular app works, but only when I use observable, the app doesn't behave like it should on real mobile devices. If someone has any idea, please give me some advices.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem, I tested with a laptop and I had the same issue. I opened the console and saw that there was an issue with the url (0 uknown), so I modified the get request url,
instead of 'http://localhost:3000', I modified to 'http://my_Ip:3000'.